# Make google sheet checkboxes toggleable but not editable

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox, protected

In sharing my google sheet I have to make the checkboxes editable to allow the user to toggle (check) the checkbox.  However, the user can edit the cell the checkbox is in which breaks the formula.

I think the answer is probably some kind of app script to restore the checkbox value if someone edits it? (Protecting the checkboxes to prevent editing makes them unusable as users can't edit the range.)  Does anybody have a script for this or some other solution?

Comment: Hi, perhaps create an `onEdit()` handler that rejects values that aren't valid?

Comment: Good idea.  I think I could write a script that changes the cell back to the oldValue (valid) after the edit. But would it be possible to reject the value so the edit doesn't occur?

Comment: An onEdit() function is triggered by a user making an  edit so and edit has to occur before an onEdit() trigger is fired.  So all you can do is undo what has already been done.  If your dealing with unfriendly users then perhaps it would be better to limit their possible destructive behavior by providing their access to you spreadsheet through a webapp.

Comment: Ok that's what I thought). I'm not concerned about unfriendly users, just want to make it idiot-proof (avoid user hitting key accidentally and replacing checkbox).  The Google Sheet presents a nice user interface for allowing checkboxes for rows of data to be checked (much better (for lots of rows of data) than Google Forms).  One problem I don't know how to solve is making the toolbars invisible (not a problem other than confusing to the user since I make them inoperable by protecting the cells from editing). I would welcome a solution to hiding the toolbars from the user.

Comment: Why was this closed?  What specifically does "opinion-based" refer to?

Comment: @Startup - I know this has been closed but have you tried just using Data Validation?  This does it for you.  If you select Data Validation for the cells you wish to insert a tick box, in the Criteria box choose Tick Box then for the On invalid data option select the Reject Input option.  Hope this helps.